# Обход покупок в своем собственном приложении

Tags: android, ios, мобильная-разработка

У меня есть приложение в Google Play и App Store. В приложении есть встроенные покупки. Могу ли я каким-то образом настроить в аккаунте или каким-либо другим способом определить, для каких пользователей покупка будет бесплатной, т.е. чтобы я мог получать функционал, который кроется за соответствующими покупками, без необходимости оплаты в своем собственном приложении?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что с этим лучше обратиться в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: Поищите, гугл вроде недавно ввел промокоды, которыми можно заменять оплату.

Comment: для тестовых аккаунтов и для создателя покупки уходят в тестовый режим

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3):

В список тестеров добавьте аккаунты в консоли разработчика. Они смогут делать тестовые покупки бесплатно.

- [Для Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-purchases).
- [Для iOS](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b997bee1).